# Getting INTERNALERROR in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Please refer to my earlier post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78220186/python-selenium-internalerror?noredirect=1#comment137899830_78220186)

I am using Python selenium library to automate an UI application. It works fine, but sometimes I am seeing INTERNALERROR error and everythings stops.This is my code:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def setup(request):
  try:
    """
    Retrieve secrets from secrets manager
    """
    secret_name = "my-secrets"
    secret_value = get_secret(secret_name)
    print(secret_value)
    secret_dict = json.loads(secret_value)
    UserName6 = secret_dict.get('UAT_USER_NAME_6')
    Password = secret_dict.get('UAT_PASSWORD')
    Client = secret_dict.get('UAT_CLIENT1')
    Uat_Url = secret_dict.get('BASE_URL_UAT')
    TestData_common.user_name6 = UserName6
    TestData_common.password = Password
    TestData_common.client = Client
    TestData_common.Url = Uat_Url
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    request.cls.driver = driver
    driver.delete_all_cookies()
    driver.get(TestData_common.Url)
    yield
    driver.quit()
except WebDriverException as e:
    print('UAT seems to be down...> ', e)

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class Test_cpty:
  def test_001_login(self):
    assert TestData_common.URL_FOUND, " UAT seems to be down..."
    print('Successfully clicked AGREE button')
    self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
    self.loginPage.do_click_agree_button()
    self.driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(2)
```

When I run the script, sometimes it errors out as INTERNALERROR. See below stacktrace for this.

```
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\myuser\repo\cfn-batch-APP\venv\Lib\site- 
packages\_pytest\main.py", line 273, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
INTERNALERROR>                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\myuser\repo\cfn-batch-APP\venv\Lib\site- 
packages\_pytest\main.py", line 327, in _main
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_runtestloop(session=session)
```

I am not sure why I get this error, it doesn't happen always though.
I have this test suite running from AWS batch env and many times (not always) it throws this error. Also sometimes when testing locally.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python selenium INTERNALERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78220186/python-selenium-internalerror)

Comment: When we close your question, you don't just get to repost the same question again 2 hours later. You need to go back to the original question and edit it, provide the info we asked for, and then petition for it to be reopened.